# How to make a custom function that builds an empty dataframe with specific column names in R

Tags: r, dataframe, function

I'm wanting to create a function that produces an empty dataframe, where the columns are passed as arguments in the function. My current attempt looks like this:

```
create_df<-function(column1, column2){
  df <- data.frame(column1=character(),
             column2=numeric(),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}
df <- create_df(a,b)
```

While this code succeeds in creating an empty `data.frame`, the column names are `column1` and `column2` rather than `a` and `b`. Is there a straightforward way to fix this?

Comment: Apologies if I haven't made this clear enough in the original post but the issue isn't creating the empty dataframe (which seems to be the question being asked in the linked post). Instead, the question is specifically how do I pass the names of the columns as arguments in a custom function which creates the empty dataframe .

Comment: @ZheyuanLi it's not just making a new `data.frame` if you read what they're looking for. I'll edit the title some to help them. 
@PaddyN I've proposed two solutions below. Usually in your question you want to provide all of the information you can about (a) what you're passing to the function (i.e., give us info about `a` and `b` by creating an example) and (b) expected output.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll make sure to include some more context in further questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending upon what you want `a` and `b` to be, you could use either of the below:

## Example inputs to function

```r
a <- "foo"
b <- "bar"
```

## Option 1: Function that gets column names from object *values*

```r
create_df_string <- function(column1, column2) {
  df <- data.frame(temp1 = character(),
                   temp2 = numeric(),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  
  colnames(df) <- c(column1, column2)
  
  return(df)
  
}
```

## Option 2: Function that gets column names from object name

```r
create_df_string(a, b)
#> [1] foo bar
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

create_df_obj <- function(column1, column2) {
  df <- data.frame(temp1 = character(),
                   temp2 = numeric(),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  
  colnames(df) <- c(deparse(substitute(column1)),
                    deparse(substitute(column2)))
  
  return(df)
  
}

create_df_obj(a, b)
#> [1] a b
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```